# Haskell, convert string into all possible "tuples" of itself

Tags: haskell, tuples, combinations

I have searched and found some solutions but none of them look as simple as what i have in mind, so you have a list of numbers `[1,2,3,4]` and want to print the tuples like this:
`[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]`

So by using

```
combinaList :: String -> String
combinaList x = [(x,y) | x <- x, y <- drop 1 x ]
```

Should do the trick, drop the first element from the list and combine the two lists, however I am getting my types wrong and possibly the drop bit too as ghci keeps on whinning at me, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try omitting the type declaration. You can always add one later if you wish. If unsure about the type, say `:t combinaList` in `ghci` (after you manage to get it compiled).

Comment: I am running from a "script" and not the ghci itself, it wouldnt compile when i ran this

Comment: If something doesn't compile, try something else. That's what `ghci` is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3atails) from `Data.List`.

```
combinaList xs = [(x, y) | (x:ys) <- tails xs, y <- ys]
```

Comment: Thanks! that makes a lot of sense too!

Comment: However, again ghci complains "Not in scope: tails", i dont understand why!

Comment: because i havent initialised the string yet maybe?

Comment: @PabloDominguezLyons You need to import `Data.List`, `:m +Data.List` or `import Data.List` at the ghci prompt, `import Data.List` in the source file.

Comment: You need to import `Data.List`. In GHCi you can also use the fully qualified name `Data.List.tails` without importing.